# calling soap + xml parsing in same activity

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

I have to develop on one app.
The first image is displayed listview using xml parsing in android .
The second image is displayed detailed description of particular order when i click the particular item.Here i wish to add the spinner update method for that particular order.(i.e)if i have to click the particular item means it is go to detailed description activity..here the 2 expandablelistview is there.they are  orderinfo,customer info...here the spinner is add orderinfo group..how is to do...how is add my code on customizedlistview and singlemenuitem activity.

[image: listview using xml parsing]
[image: detailed description of particular item]

please  refer my code here:
[CustomizedListView](http://pastie.org/4624429) 
[SingleMenuItemActivity](http://pastie.org/4624465)

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand your question. If i'm wrong say it..
You want to crate an "spinner update method" in the second view, which parse the xml for a soap request, then send the soap request and split the response?

If yes, I would recommend you to make an saparate class in which you will parse the xml and make the request. Something like this:

```
public class SomeRequest {
    private static String xml = null;
    private static String response= null;

    public static void SomeRequest (String url, String sT, int protocoll, String[] Vars) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:mob='YOUR/URL' xmlns:arr='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>" +
                "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                "<soapenv:Body>" +
                "<mob:Request>" +
                    "<!--Optional:-->" +
                    "<mob:Vars>" +
                        "<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->" +
                        "<arr:string>"+ Vars +"</arr:string>" +
                    "</mob:Vars>" +
                    "<!--Optional:-->" +
                    "<mob:protocoll>"+ protocoll +"</mob:protocoll>" +
                    "<!--Optional:-->" +
                    "<mob:session>"+ sT +"</mob:session>" +
                "</mob:Request>" +
            "</soapenv:Body>" +
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml, HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", "YOUR/REQUEST/URL");
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response= EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            Log.e("httpRequestException", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes second view have to display xml parsing details and also spinner update using soap call method also...so please check it my code and give me solutios

Comment: create a new class like in my exampample above, which will handle the request. then craete some variables in this class, define geter and seter. Let the response split and set the variable. Initialize this class in the SingleMenuItemActivity. after that you can get the content with the geter.